# Unix restrict user to list only user owned files in a directory

Tags: permissions

I have a directory say `/data` and 3 users - user1, user2, user3

each user has a folder in `/data`

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lrt /data
total 64
drwx------.  2 root        root        16384 May 19  2017 lost+found
drwx------.  2 user1       user1        4096 Jun  7  2017 user1
drwx------.  3 user2       user2        4096 Jun 12  2017 user2
drwx------.  2 user3       user3        4096 Jul 16  2017 user3
```

How do I set permissions so that when user1 logs in and `cd`'s into `/data` and does a `ls -lrt` or maybe logs in via `winscp` or any random ftp/sftp software, they would be able to list only "user1" directory and the rest of the directories are invisible to him.

eg. should be visible as below

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ ls -lrt /data
total ??
drwx------.  2 user1       user1        4096 Jun  7  2017 user1
[user1@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done. But you can set the permissions on /data to --x for others, so they can only (blindly) cd into their directory but not see the contents of /data at all:

```
# chmod 771 /data
```

Comment: One _could_ do it (I think) if the main directory is located on an NFS server and the clients automounted from it.

Comment: @Kusalananda The directory where `server:/data` is mounted would still have to be executable so that the users would be able to traverse it to get into the respective `user` directories. Whether it's that way or the way in ctrl-d's answer, the user's wouldn't be able to `ls-l` from inside of `/data` and list the directories that they don't own but they'd be able to directly `ls -l /data/user#` if they knew that the directory was there and the name of it. With that being said, it is possible but it just doesn't cover every scenario.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible using traditional mode permissions in Unix. This is due to the fact that the permissions to read a directory are required to read the contents of said directory.

#### Example

I'm going to use the `su` command to illustrate why. I've set up 3 user accounts, user1, user2, and user3.

```
$ su -c 'whoami' user1
user1
$ su -c 'whoami' user2
user2
$ su -c 'whoami' user3
user3
```

Here's my directory structure:

```
$ mkdir -p /data/user{1..3}
$ for i in {1..3};do chown user${i}:user${i} /data/user${i};done

$ ls -l /data/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Jun 30 11:35 user1
drwxr-xr-x 2 user2 user2 4096 Jun 30 11:35 user2
drwxr-xr-x 2 user3 user3 4096 Jun 30 11:35 user3
```

If we set the permissions such that no user can read the `/data` then no user can do a `ls -l /data`.

```
$ chmod 750 /data

$ su -c 'ls -l /data' user1
ls: cannot open directory /data/: Permission denied
```

In order to allow a user that's not the owner (root) or in the group (root), we have to enable the `r-x` permissions for anyone (ie. the other permissions).

If we just enabled the `r--` permissions the user's could list some aspects of the directory but not acquire things such as the permissions of the contents within the directory.

```
$ chmod 754 /data

$ su -c 'ls -l /data/' user1
ls: cannot access /data/user3: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /data/user2: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /data/user1: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? user1
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? user2
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? user3
```

If we try and give user's just execute permissions, `--x`, they can access the sub-directories of `/data` but cannot perform any listing of the contents of `/data`.

```
$ chmod 755 /data

$ su -c 'ls -l /data/' user1
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Jun 30 11:35 user1
drwxr-xr-x 2 user2 user2 4096 Jun 30 11:35 user2
drwxr-xr-x 2 user3 user3 4096 Jun 30 11:35 user3
```

#### What about ACLs?

Could using access control lists (ACLs) work here? In investigating this I don't think they can give you anything better.

Here I'm resetting the permissions to 750 on `/data`, and added an ACL for user1 to `/data` or `--x`:

```
$ chmod 750 /data
$ setfacl -m u:user1:x /data

$ ls -ld /data
drwxr-x---+ 5 root root 4096 Jun 30 11:35 /data
```

Our user, user1, is now no longer able to access `/data`:

```
$ su -c 'ls -l /data' user1
ls: cannot open directory /data: Permission denied
```

But can still see the sub-dir `/data/user1`:

```
$ su -c 'ls -l /data/user1' user1
total 0
```

This is the effect the `setfacl` had on permissions:

```
    $ getfacl /data
    # file: data
    # owner: root
    # group: root
    user::rwx
    user:user1:--x
    group::r-x
    mask::r-x
    other::---
```

#### What's the issue?

The problem is that in order to have access to list the contents of a directory, mainly `/data`, user's need `r--` permissions to do this. We cannot explicitly give out 'portions' of this, it's all or nothing in the world of mode permissions in Unix.